# Spring Boot 2 Authorization Server for public clients (PKCE)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

is possible create authorization server for PKCE authentication in current version of spring security?

I did research and I found out this authorization server project https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server but there is no usable sample for that project.

I also find out that spring recommends Keycloak as authorization server, but it is not fit for my case.
We need be able fetch and verify user against remote service, and then use authorization server only for generating and verifying jwt tokens. In my knowledge Keycloak should holds also users right? So the best solution would be custom spring standalone authorization server. Is it possible in some way? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You may have a look to this project: [CloudFoundry User Account and Authentication (UAA) Server](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa).
`UAA` is a (Spring MVC) component of `Cloud Foundry` but it could be used as a stand alone `OAuth2 server`. It can support external authentication service. And there is a Pull Request that implements PKCE: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/pull/939 (not yet merged, but under review).

You can find an example on how to use `UAA` on [baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/cloud-foundry-uaa).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Spring framework has one more implementation of the authorization server.  It is a part of [spring-security-oauth](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth#overview) project. But this project was moved into maintenance mode.

According to this [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide), the new authorization server project (that you have already found) will be created to change the legacy solution.

From my point of view now there are several possible options:

1. Using old legacy [spring-security-oauth](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth#overview). More examples with [old auth server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples)
2. Using external services like Keycloak, Auth0, Okta and etc

Comment: But if I right there is no support for PKCE in old oauth project. That si why asked this question. External service is not possible to use because we need fetch user from different identity provider, and then generate jwt by ourself.

Comment: some time ago I have done some research about possible options with spring auth server and unfortunately, I haven't found any except options from my answer


in any way, I wish you good luck with solving your issue